# seperate copies of static variable in children classes

Tags: c#, oop, .net-core

I'm using a vendor library (which I can not modify) that has certain class with static variable

```
class P {
    protected static string key = null;

    public static string Key { 
        get {return key;} 
        private set {key = value;} 
    }

    public P(string key) {Key=key;}

    // other functions that use the key...
}
```

I want to use two different keys in my dotnet-core api controller based on certain condition.

```
public class Controller: ControllerBase {
    private readonly P p1, p2;
    public Controller(IConfiguration configuration) {
        p1 = new P(_configuration.GetValue<string>("key1"));
        p2 = new P(_configuration.GetValue<string>("key2"));
    }
    // use p1 or p2 based on request
}
```

Initialy I used to call the constructor inside my controller to set the key, but problem is, in case of multiple requests at same time, everything get's messed up.

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetData(int id) {
    if (id<100) p = new P(_configuration.GetValue<string>("key1"))
    else p = new P(_configuration.GetValue<string>("key2"));
    // use p
}
```

I also tried creating seperate child classes but I still have only single copy of the static variable

```
class C1:P {
    public C1(string key): base(key) { }
}
class C2:P {
    public C2(string key): base(key) { }
}

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        C1 c1 = new C1("first");
        C2 c2 = new C2("second");
        Console.WriteLine(C1.Key); 
        // desired-output: first, actual-output: second
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to achive this?

Comment: There isn't one. There are no static variables. What you posted shows a static field exposed through a static property and a static method. Static fields are defined on the type itself. Their value is shared across all instances of a type

Comment: I don't think there is a correct way of doing this, it's shared state. Either there's a deliberate reason it's designed like this, or it's incorrect and should be changed (setting a static from the constructor seems very odd to me). Without any details, I can only suggest talking to the vendor.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, It's basically a payment gateway integration and based on my country's regulatory requirements we need to maintain seperate accounts for two different types of transactions.

Comment: There may be better ideas, but the only way I could think of to accomplish this would be to have separate micro-services as their own application instances for each of these values.  Basically it would just be a pass-thru service for the vendor library.  Then your application would conditionally invoke one service or the other.  It's an extra HTTP call on the operation, but can be pretty optimized.  (Or maybe not even HTTP, maybe they're locally hosted applications you invoke via command-line calls.)

Comment: Payment gateways use APIs and their libraries are essentially convenience wrappers over the APIs. First, check whether the library is available as source code. For example, Checkout.com hosts their SDK [on Github](https://github.com/checkout/checkout-sdk-net). If the source isn't available, you can use the API directly instead of using the library. Payment gateways aren't paid to produce good quality clients and sometimes the clients are hastily built, badly designed if not outright ported from one language to the next

Comment: The gateway may even have a Swagger/OpenAPI document in which case you could generate a client from the OpenAPI definition.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was trying to avoid that but I guess it's the only way now. Thanks for your input everyone.